# nodemailer is blocked on a hosted Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, nodemailer

I have been fighting this issue for a week with the help of support from the hoster and smart Linux admins. Postfix is up and running, the mail user exists. We did not install a firewall.

It would be a big help if you could narrow down my problem. Does someone else have the same issue? Is nodemailer the right library?

It makes no difference if I run the script on the Ubuntu instance itself (localhost) or from my local workstation.

Fiddling with ports and servernames did not sort any result.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// Works ok
//var mailUser = 'jelle@googlemail.com'
//var mailPwd = '<pwd>'
//var mailService = 'gmail'

/** fails with log ..

{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:465
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
  code: 'ECONNECTION',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 465,
  command: 'CONN' }

 */
var mailUser = 'jelle@file.com'
var mailPwd = '<pwd>'
var mailService = 'file.com'

// prepare the email server connection settings
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service : mailService,
    port : 465,
    secure : true, // use SSL on port 465 else 587
    auth : {
        user : mailUser,
        pass : mailPwd
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from : 'jelle@file.com',
    to : '<any email address>',
    subject : '<subject>',
    text : '<text>'
};


function sendMail() {
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    })
}

sendMail();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very smart freelancer from Belgrade on the job. He reinstalled postfix and fixed the issue as follows.

```
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: mailService,
    port: 25,
    secure:false,
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
}));
```

Works fine now.

Please note that it is intended to operate from localhost.